# VHDL - library doesn't work

Tags: iis, vhdl, quartus

I've create a new project on Quartus II with VHDL, but after I run it give me the errors shown below. Do you have any idea why?

> Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at test_VHDL.vhd(5): design library "work" does not contain primary unit "std_arith"
>
> Error (10800): VHDL error at test_VHDL.vhd(5): selected name in use clause is not an expanded name
>
> Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 2 errors, 1 warning
>   Error: Peak virtual memory: 1003 megabytes
>   Error: Processing ended: Sat Dec  5 19:50:39 2015
>   Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:13
>   Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:38
>   Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 1 warning

Here is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library work;
use work.std_arith.all;                              --extinde operatorul ” + “ la opera]ii \ntre semnale 
                                                                  --[i numere \ntregi
entity SUM is
    port    (a : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         b : in std_logic;
         ini,start,clk,a_disponibil,b_disponibil : in std_logic;
         sum : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
         q : inout std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end SUM;

architecture arch_SUM of SUM is

    signal load_a,load_b,reset,load_s : std_logic;
    signal z : std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
        type STARE is (S0,S1,S2,S3,S4);                                  --st`rile automatului
        signal S : STARE;
begin

    --NUMARATOR
            ---------------------------------------------------------------

    NUM : process(b)
    begin
        if rising_edge(b) then 
            if reset='1' then q<=(others=>'0');
            elsif load_a='1' then 
                for i in 3 downto 0 loop                     --\ncarc` operandul a 
                    q(i) <= a(i);                              --\n ultimii 3 bistabili 
                end loop;                                             --ai num`r`torului
            elsif  load_b='1' then     
                    q <= q+1;                                                 --adun`  b  la  a
            end if;
        end if;
    end process NUM;

    --REGISTRU
            --------------------------------------------------------------------

    REG: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
                if  reset='1' then sum<=(others=>'0');
                elsif  load_s='1' then 
                    sum<=q;
                end if;
        end if;
    end process REG;

    --AUTOMAT
           -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AUTOMAT : process(ini,clk)      
    begin
        if  INI='1'  then  s<=S0;                                           --ini]ializeaz` automatul
        elsif  rising_edge(clk)  then 
                       case S is                                                      --descrie diagrama st`rilor
                when S0 =>
                    if  start='1'  then  S<=S1;
                                         else S<=S0;
                                           end if;
                when S1 =>
                    if  a_disponibil='1' then S<=S2;
                                                else S<=S1;
                    end if;
                when S2 =>
                    if  b_disponibil='1'  then  S<=S3;
                                                              else S<=S2;
                    end if;          
                when S3 =>
                    if  b_disponibil='0' then S<=S4;
                                                            else S<=S3;
                    end if;
                when S4 =>  S<=S0;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process AUTOMAT;

    with S select
             z<= "0000"  when  S0,                                                --genereaz` ie[irea 
            "0010"  when  S1,
            "1000"  when  S2,
            "0100"  when  S3,
            "0001"  when  others;

    load_a <= z(0);
    load_b <= z(1);                                                                             --conexiuni interne
    reset    <= z(2);
    load_s <= z(3);

end arch_SUM;
```

Have anyone idea why and how can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `use work.std_arith.all;` introduces the sysnthesis compiler to look for a package `std_arith` in the same library as of the VHDL file. If you didn't specify one in the Quartus project settings, that it will be the default library. In this case, you have to provide your own implementation of the package and to add this file to the Quartus project as well.

If you are looking for the non-standard package from Synopsys, then you must change the line to `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;`. But, this library does not define an operator `+` for the type `std_logic_vector`. **EDIT** The required operator is defined in the package `std_logic_unsigned`, if you want to treat your `std_logic_vector`s as unsigned numbers. The package is included with `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;`. If you want signed arithmetic instead, then include `use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;`.

But, I recommend to use the standard IEEE library `ieee.numeric_std` instead, which defines arithmetic operators on the vector-types `unsigned` and `signed`.

For example, declare in the entity

```
sum : out unsigned(4 downto 0);
q : inout unsigned(4 downto 0);
```

Comment: And how can I add that library if he is not defined? Or I can use just ieee.std_logic_arith.all; ?

Comment: @J.D What did you mean? Do you actually have an implementation of the  package `std_arith` available?

Comment: What did you mean by _already implemented_?  By whom? Quartus?

Comment: Alternately, using the Synopsys libraries you can change the use clause on line 5 to be `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` after which the question's code analyzes successfully.